# JSON.NET \ how to concat two JSONs in JSon.net

Tags: c#, json.net, concatenation

I have two JSONs (as simple strings) - is there neat way to concat them?
As part of the infrastructure??

Comment: Do you want to concat in C# or jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string j1 = @"{""a"":1}";
string j2 = @"{""b"":2}";

var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j1), 
                                            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j2) });
```

or

```
var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { obj1 = JObject.Parse(j1), 
                                          obj2 = JObject.Parse(j2) });
```