# Is there any way to serialize the object without `{}` using json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Actually I am using **Json.net** for serializing the object into a json string, in that i faced a suituation in which i want to serialize the object without the `{}` in my Json String. Is there any way to do that..

**Example:** Here is the class

```
public class Sample
{
  public String name{get;set;}
  public int id{get;set;}
}
```

While serializing the object of the  above class, I get something like below

```
{"name":....,
 "id":...}
```

But I dont want those `{}` wrapping around the json string.
I need as below,

```
"name":....,
 "id":...
```

So is there any way in json.net to remove them or am i need to do it using String operations?

**For Example:**

My two classes are as follow,

```
pulbic class Class1
 {
public String prop1{get;set;}
public String prop2{get;set;}
public Class2 classprop{get;set;}
  }

 public class Class2
{
public String prop3{get;set;}
public String prop4{get;set;}
 }
```

When I am creating the object for class Class1 as follow and serialize i am getting the json string as follow,

```
Class1 c1=new Class1(){prop1="hi",prop2="hey",classprop=new Class1(){prop3="bye";prop4="byyyyye"}
```

`{
    "prop1":"hi",
    "prop2":"hey",
    "classprop":{
        "prop3":"bye",
        "prop4":"byyyyye"
            }
}`

But i need the string as follow,
`{
    "prop1":"hi",
    "prop2":"hey",
    "prop3":"bye",
    "prop4":"byyyyye"

}`

Do you have any way solve this situation??

Comment: So you want a JSON serializer to serialize your object in a way that produces completely invalid JSON?  `"name": "value", "id": 5` is not valid JSON at all.

Comment: What i am going to do is append this json string into an another json string thats why i am asking or **is there any way to append two json string using json.net?**

Comment: why not perform that nesting pre-serialization via either anonymous types or a dictionary?

Comment: I am not good at that can you provide me a simple example??

Comment: hmm, please provide your sample composite JSON, and the two classes whose properties your are trying to combine, and we can probably give you a good example.

Comment: Have a look at this thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913396/json-net-how-to-concat-two-jsons-in-json-net  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I think it might be helpful thanks buddy..